# How do i Draw on a Frame in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, draw, qpainter

Ok so i have created my UI with the drag and drop part of Qt and in the Ui i created a "Tab Widget" inside another "Tab Widget". Now, inside the second Tab Widget i created a Frame

My Question is, how do i draw on top of this frame in Qt?

i tried this but no luck at all. Ive tried different ways on going about this, the program runs good but when i go and see if the frame was drawn on, i see nothing...please help me with this, with code example and all. Thanks in advance.

```
void 2ndMainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter paint(ui->rightTriangle_frame);
    paint.drawEllipse(10,10,100,100);
    paint.setPen(Qt::red);


    paint.end();
}
```

## The way i finally did it for those others that would like to know

my header file included this under the private slot

```
    Ui::GeometryMainWindow *ui;

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rectangle;
```

## In my .cpp file i did this

```
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackpen(Qt::black);
    blackpen.setWidth(6);

    ellipse = scene->addEllipse(10,10,100,100,blackpen,redBrush);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to draw some customized shapes on QFrame, I suggest you to use a QGraphicsView instead of QFrame. Implementing the paintEvent of a widget may create performance issues. If you use a QGraphicsView, you can create a QGraphicsScene and add your items to that scene which is the general and accepted way of doing this kind of stuff.

Alternatively, implement an eventFilter as below,

```
bool 2ndMainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
    paintEvent((QPaintEvent *)e);
}
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(o, e);
}
```

In constructor of your mainwindow add,

```
installEventFilter(this);
```

By the way, you should set your pen before drawing your ellipse in paintEvent function.

Comment: I tried this but another way doing this instead, it worked exactly how i wanted thanks alot =)

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen bluepen(Qt::black);
    bluepen.setWidth(6);

    ellipse = scene->addEllipse(10,10,100,100,bluepen,redBrush);

and header was 

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rectangle;

i didnt really do what you said but i did use hraphics view which helped ALOT, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are overriding the `paintEvent()` method of your **main window** and from there trying to paint on the frame widget. Look at your console output - you should get a message like

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

Instead, subclass your `QFrame` widget (in Qt designer, select "Promote to ..." to define the user defined subclass) and in this subclass, override `paintEvent` like this:

```
void MyFrame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.setPen(Qt::red);
    paint.drawEllipse(10,10,100,100);

    paint.end();
    QFrame::paintEvent(e);
}
```

Note that, in order to draw a red ellipse, you need to set the pen color before drawing the ellipse, of course. You should also call the `paintEvent()` method of the parent class in order to draw the frame border.

See https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/QtRepaint for an SSCCE.

Comment: i followed what you said word by word and i get this error now, 

error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' 

and 

error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

it says that because instead of being 

QWidget *Right_Triangle_Tab; (being declared as a QWidget like everything else) 

now it shows like this, 

rightTriangle_frame *rightTriangle_frame; 
I tried doing QFrame rightTriangle_frame *rightTriangle_frame; but it doesnt work....what should i do?

Comment: You should rename your class `rightTriangle_frame` (in Qt designer) to something like `RightTriangleFrame` and add a `RightTriangleFrame.cpp` and a `RightTriangleFrame.h` file to your project. In this file, implement the `class RightTriangleFrame : public QFrame`. See the `MyFrame.cpp` / `MyFrame.h` files from the link in my answer.

Comment: i already did all of that already, i fixed that error, i get no error now but i still cannot see the drawing on top of the frame =(, there has to be something im missing here...i just cant fiind out what it is

Comment: Can you shrink down your code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue and post the relevant parts in your question? (Probably its better to post a new question, in order to not pollute this one)